# Python ics language encoding

Tags: python, icalendar

I have this .ics file that I would like to import into python.

I am using the requests and ics libraries to do so.

When I try printing the contents of the calendar (Which include Hebrew letters) I am getting gibberish.
however, I tried doing the same procedure with another calendar which also includes Hebrew letters it worked perfectly fine.

This is my code.

```
import requests as rq
from ics import Calendar

url = "https://example.com/cal/"

c = Calendar(rq.get(url).text)

for event in list(c.events):
    print(event)
```

I am getting this output

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20210322T123000Z
DESCRIPTION: ×××× ××××¢× ××××©× ×'\n×§×××¦× 11\n×ª×¨××× ××¡×¤×¨ 1\n××ª×¨××/×ª: ××¨×× ××\n14:30-16:30
DTEND:20210322T143000Z
LOCATION:××××× 805
DTSTART:20210322T123000Z
SUMMARY:×ª×¨××× 234114
TRANSP:OPAQUE
UID:202002.234114.LG11.1.×.14:30 
URL:
END:VEVENT
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requests`' `.text` tries to guess the encoding of the contents (previously using `chardet`, these days using `charset_normalizer`). It can be wrong sometimes, resulting in gibberish.

According to a quick google, the likely encoding for Hebrew is [ISO-8859-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-8). (EDIT: as figured out in comments, it was actually plain UTF-8.)

Try

```
resp = requests.get(url)
resp.raise_for_status()
text = resp.content.decode("ISO-8859-8")
c = Calendar(text)
```

to be explicit about the encoding?

Comment: Then the file isn't ISO-8859-8. You'll need to figure out what exactly it is. (Try `UTF-8`, just in case?)